# Importing and Exporting UserForms and Modules

Tags: excel, vba, userform, import-module

HELP!  I cannot find this anywhere...  I have found plenty of explanations of .frx files but that is not the issue.  I have exported 2 modules ".bas" and a userform ".frm" that also created the ".frx" binary file.  The issue is that now when I import them to a new workbook with the code below, upon initializing the userform, the application opens and tries to run in the original workbook, in which I wrote the modules and designed the custom userform.  Why is this happening and is there a way to get it to load the userform in the workbook that the form and modules were imported into?

```
Sub Import_VBA(WBName)

    Dim VBc As Variant
    Dim exportFolder As String, VBcExt As String, testFile As String
    Dim newWB As Workbook

    testFile = WBName
    exportFolder = "y:\ECI\Database\Outputs\InterfaceApp"
    Set newWB = Workbooks(testFile & ".xlsm")

    '''''  Test VBA protection
    On Error Resume Next
    If newWB.VBProject.Protection <> 0 Then

        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            Err.Clear
            MsgBox "VBA Project Object Model is protected in " & newWB.Name & vbCrLf _
            & vbCrLf & "Please remove VBA protection in Trust Center to continue.", _
            vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"

            Set newWB = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
            Set newWB = Nothing
            Err.Clear
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End If

    ''''' Add Interface App Components
    For Each VBc In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(exportFolder).Files
        Select Case LCase(Right(VBc.Name, 4))
        Case ".bas", ".frm", ".cls", ".frx"
            newWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import exportFolder & "\" & VBc.Name
        End Select
    Next VBc
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you calling this method? Is there any code in the UserForm_Initialize/UserForm_Activate of the form you are importing?

Comment: I was under the impression the code for the form goes with it when exported?  Do I need to do that separately?  Here is the code..

Comment: He asked because whatever WB is passed in to `Import_VBA(WBName)` is opened. We can't see that happening from here. You need to post the code behind the userform where the initialization happens.